# jenkins running on docker not accessible through localhost

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using the standard docker commands to pull and run jenkins image on my docker instance as below. Please throw some light what's possibly going wrong here and any suggestions how to fix it.

```
******-M-T2EK:Jenkins $ docker run -p 8090:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:56 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:56 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Logging initialized @1087ms
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:56 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:58 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Oct 27, 2019 7:06:59 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Oct 27, 2019 7:07:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started w.@47404bea{/,file:/var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
Oct 27, 2019 7:07:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started ServerConnector@15c25153{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Oct 27, 2019 7:07:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started @4442ms
Oct 27, 2019 7:07:00 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
....


Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

c113b006b4d149039e5deee9562880ba

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Oct 27, 2019 7:08:33 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Oct 27, 2019 7:08:33 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
Oct 27, 2019 7:08:35 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
Oct 27, 2019 7:08:35 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 79,278 ms
Oct 27, 2019 7:08:38 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Oct 27, 2019 7:08:38 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
--> setting agent port for jnlp
--> setting agent port for jnlp... done
```

For some reason, It's stuck in the loading stage.

```
******-M-T2EK:Jenkins $ wget http://localhost:8090/
--2019-10-27 12:09:08--  http://localhost:8090/
wget: /Users/************/.netrc:1: unknown token "Welcome9$"
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8090... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Comment: Did you read official installation document https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/? Unlocking Jenkins section.

Comment: @Sers, Thanks for the doc link. I followed a similar documentation and as you can see in the above commands did the installation as mentioned in it. Its still not working. I suspect there's some firewall setting that stopping it from accessing this jenkins instance. Also, nothing loads from the request to get into unlocking stage.